# Fiat-Shamir transform: reliance on hash input by interactive proof

Tags: hash, fiat-shamir

Peggy would like to prove to Victor that she knows the discrete logarithm of $y$ based $g$; that is, she knows $x$ such that $y = g^x \bmod p$. One round of the interactive proof protocol consists of the following steps.

1. Peggy picks random $k \in \mathbb Z/(p−1)\mathbb Z$, computes $t = g^k \bmod p$, and sends $t$ to Victor.
2. Victor picks random $h \in \mathbb Z/(p−1)\mathbb Z$ and sends $h$ to Peggy.
3. Peggy computes $r = (k − hx) \bmod (p − 1)$ and sends $r$ to Victor.
4. Victor verifies that $t = g^r y^h \bmod p$.

The interactive protocol can be converted into a noninteractive zero-knowledge proof by choosing and making public a collision-resistant hash function $H$, and changing the second step of the interactive protocol to the following: Peggy computes $h = H(y, t)$. Then the noninteractive proof consists of $(t, h, r)$, which can be verified as follows: $$h = H(y, t), \qquad t \stackrel?= g^r y^h \bmod p.$$

1. What is the problem if in the non-interactive proof the hash $h$ depends only on $y$? That is, $h = H(y)$, and the proof consists of $(t, h, r)$, which can be verified as follows: $$h = H(y), \qquad t \stackrel?= g^r y^h \bmod p.$$
2. What is the problem if in the non-interactive proof the hash $h$ depends only on $t$? That is, $h = H(t)$, and the proof consists of $(t, h, r)$, which can be verified as follows: $$h = H(t), \qquad t \stackrel?= g^r y^h \bmod p.$$

Comment: What have you tried to do to approach this?  Hint: As a _forger_, you are not constrained to run the protocol as it is written; you just have to find a triple of values $(t, h, r)$, and possibly $y$, that will fool a verifier without using $x = \log_g y$ directly.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I am trying to figure out weakness in NI Fiat-Shamir protocol. As in the 3 stage original Fiat Shamir the hash is sent along with the mesaage and the hash consists of the message y and the random t , but what if we only hash the message y or the random t and then the verifier inturn verifies as stated above will also work . My goal is to find the weakness to exploit it .? Thanks a lot

Comment: Usually $t$ is not included in the signature; did you really mean to include it as a triple $(t, h, r)$, or did you mean a pair $(h, r)$?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I do not think sending the hash of t also along makes any difference as the adversary(be it the prover or verifier or anyone) wont be able to get any meaningful info from it as it a one way function ?
https://www.cryptologie.net/article/193/schnorrs-signature-and-non-interactive-protocols/  
The random t is not included ! Please refer this but including also wont make any difference? Thanks

Comment: Or, alternatively, the signature is usually $(t, r)$ with $h$ recomputed.  Making the signature more complicated may not hurt security but it certainly doesn't help—and, in principle, it might hurt a great deal, _e.g._ if a verifier only checks $t \stackrel?= g^r y^h$.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage But yeah if I send (t,h,r) how does it effect the hash of only y or t? And also if i send only (h,r) what difference does it make?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage the above protocol is another way of making a interactive to non-interactive . In the simple trend we send (h,r) but in this I am sending (t,h,r) and inturn it is verified h = H(y,t)!

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I found an answer in this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/771.pdf  (page 6) and i posted it below for the 2nd part of the question. But I am unable to understand that can you please look at it once and see if it makes sense to you? thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the verification of Fiat Shamir wrong. The proof consists of $(h,r)$ and $y$ which is public anyway and only the relation $h = H(y,g^r y^h)$ is checked. As a result in your first case the proof is trivially valid. Your second case is interesting as it is not secure against an adaptive adversary. There is a paper by  David Bernhard, Olivier Pereira and Bogdan Warinschi on this issue which considers its applications to e-voting as well. Please take a look  at https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/771 page 6.

Comment: Hello sir I found the answer to the 2nd part in the paper you suggested and I posted it below but I am not able to understand it can you please explain if it makes sense to you thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The Schnorr  signature scheme is the weak Fiat-Shamir
transformation of the Schnorr identification protocol. In a group G of order q
generated by G, it proves knowledge of an exponent x satisfying the equation
X = G^x for a known X. Viewing (x, X) as a signing/verification key pair and
including a message in the hash input yields a signature of knowledge.
To create a proof, the prover picks a random a ← Zq and computes A = G^a.
He then hashes A to create a challenge c = H(A). Finally he computes f = a+cx;
the proof is the pair (c, f) and the verification procedure consists in checking
the equation c= H(G^f/X^c)
The weak Fiat-Shamir transformation can safely be used here, as discussed
in previous analysis  since the public key X is selected first and given as
input to the adversary who tries to produce a forgery.
However, if the goal of the adversary is to build a valid triple (X, c, f) for any
X of his choice, then this protocol is not a proof of knowledge anymore unless
the discrete logarithm problem is easy in G. Suppose indeed that there is an
extractor K that, by interacting with any prover P that provides a valid triple
(X, c, f), extracts x = log(baseG)(X). This extractor can be used to solve an instance
Y of the discrete logarithm problem with respect to (G, G) as follows: use Y as
the proof commitment, compute c = H(Y ), choose f ← Zq and set X = ( G^f/y)^(1/c).
Since the proof (Y, c, f) passes the verification procedure for statement X, the extractor K should be able to compute x = log(base G)(X) by interacting with our
prover. We now observe that, by taking the discrete logarithm in base G on
both sides of the definition of X, we obtain the solution log(baseG)(Y ) = f − cx to
the discrete logarithm challenge.